# Is it possible to load a single row from a CSV file?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Using PHP, is it possible to load just a single record / row from a CSV file?

In other words, I would like to treat the file as an array, but don't want to load the entire file into memory.

I know this is really what a database is for, but I am just looking for a down and dirty solution to use during development.

Edit: To clarify, I know exactly which row contains the info I am looking for.

I would just like to know if there is a way to get it without having to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: Yes, you can load a single row using `fgetcsv`. Beyond that the question is a bit vague. What further requirements do you have for that row? Do you want to load it from the middle of the file, from an unknown position, filtered by some condition...?

Comment: it is not possible. You just have to read through each row till you find what you are looking for.  I have seen a couple scripts out there that abstract it away for you, so you can write "queries", but under the hood it still works the same. edit: well you can read it 1 row at a time but i *assume* what you mean to do is select a specific row

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are looking for a row with certain data. Therefore you could probably implement the following logic:
(1) scan file for the given data (ex. value which is in the row that you are trying to find),
(2) load only this line of file,
(3) perform your operations on that line.

Answer (score 0):

`fgetcsv()` operates over a file resource handle, so if you want you can obtain the position of the line you can `fseek()` the resource to that position and use `fgetcsv()` normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which line you are looking for until after you have read the row, your best bet is reading the record until you find the record by testing the array that is returned.

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
while(false !== ($data = fgetcsv($fp, 0, ','))) {
   if ($data['field'] === 'somevalue') {
      echo 'Hurray';
      break;
   }
}
```

If you are looking to read a specific line, use the splfile object and seek to the record number. This will return a string that you must convert to an array

```
$file = new SplFileObject('data.csv');
$file->seek(2);
$record = $file->current();
$data = explode(",", $record);
```